# How can I get the resultcode from an activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, onactivityresult

I have one checkbox which creates a Bluetooth connection. The problems is that when the Bluetooth permission request dialog box appears and I choose `No`, the checkbox still remains checked.

How can I get the requestcode from this activity, and put the checkbox to off if I get `RESULT_CANCELED`?

```
CheckBox turnBtOnOff=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
turnBtOnOff.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {
            if (isChecked)
            {
                if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
                {
                    Intent enableBtIntent=new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                    startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);  
                    //myAddress=mBluetoothAdapter.getAddress();
                    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), myAddress, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if(mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
                    {
                        mBluetoothAdapter.disable();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode ==REQUEST_ENABLE_BT) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            turnBtOnOff.setSelected(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                ......
            }
            break;
        }

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
private static int RESULT_OK=111;
private static int  PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST=112;

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
             Intent data) {
         if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
             if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                 // ....do your code here
                 // 

             }
         }
     }
```

good luck

Answer (score 0):

you need to override **onActivityResult** to get results back from an activity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    //if 12345 is the int value you used to start bluetooth activity then
    if(requestCode == 12345){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            //do whatever you want
        }
        else{
            //do whatever you want
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override the `onActivityResult()` method:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        //check for the requestcode here and check/uncheck the checkbox 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a Little old, but I had the same problem today, this is my solution working on android 4.4.2

```
@Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {      
    if(resultCode==RESULT_FIRST_USER){
        //custom request is BLUETOOTH_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE
                        if(requestCode==BLUETOOTH_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE){
                            //Do something
                        }
                    }
 }
```

the result is not RESULT_OK, because its not an operation to perform, its a user-defined acitivty.